# XPath select td-nodes in table depending on inner Text of upper td

Tags: xpath, html-table

I've got a HTML document with some tables:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text that is important</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="50" class="content">Some text</td>
        <td height="100" class="content">Some other text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text that is not important</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="50" class="content">Some text</td>
        <td height="100" class="content">Some other text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract all `<td>`-tags from a table with the attribute `height="50"` and `class="content"` when another `<td>` in the table contains "Some text that is important".

I tried so many things but I don't quite get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required output:

```
//tr[td="Some text that is important"]/following-sibling::tr/td[@height='50' and @class='content']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XPath-1.0 expression to get the wanted `table` node's `td` tags:

```
//table[tr/td[@height='50' and @class='content'] and contains(tr/td/text(),'Some text that is important')]/tr/td
```

This retrieves the first `table` node's `td`s.
Its output are *all `td` tags* of the matching `table` node:

```
<td>Some text that is important</td>
<td height="50" class="content">Some text</td>
<td height="100" class="content">Some other text</td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an empty result set. But even `//table/tr/td` is empty. If I do `//table//tr//td` I get some nodes back.